# Summarise_each for first non-NA value

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Is there a way to instruct `dplyr` to use `summarise_each` with specification `first` and `na.rm=TRUE`?

I have a dataframe with many NAs and numeric values. Column A is patient ID. I would like to summarise the dataframe according to patient ID by taking the first non-NA of each variables. This didn't work

```
`summarised_df <- df %>% group_by(patient_ID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(first(., na.rm=TRUE)))`
```

Thanks in advance!

Here you can find an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz3Dz.png) of the data. However, the original data includes hundreds of different variables.

Comment: Can you provide your dataset as an example and the expected output? copy and paste output of `dput(my_dat)` into your question. This will give better context to future readers so they don't have to imagine what your dataset looks like.

Comment: Hi @useR. Thanks for the comment. You have right, providing an example would have been easier. Luckily Psidom managed to find the solution!

Comment: FYI, you should still provide an example and expected output even though you accepted an answer as SO is meant to benefit a community, not solely the asker of the question.

Comment: @useR I updated the post with an example

Comment: Please use `dput(my_dat)` instead of posting it as an image

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `first(na.omit(.))` or `na.omit(.)[1]`. Besides `summarise_each` is deprecated, use `summarise_all` instead.